# Change the display style of multiple divs using jquery - language selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, display

**EDIT**
So I've solved it - for future reference if anyone finds this via searching:
I gave the parent div's of each language ('divGer' + 'divFre') that i wanted hidden on page load a 'style="display:none;"' - then when selecting each language link the javascript showed those divs.

thanks again for all your help!

**UPDATED**

Hi,

So, After some fiddling and more googling, I managed to get it to work. The 2 divs I had for each language, I wrapped into one parent div. and the below Javascript works - but when you first load the page it shows all languages, then shows 1 language depending which lang you select at the top.

HTML:

```
<a class="showSingle" target="Eng">English</a>
<a class="showSingle" target="Ger">Deutsch</a>
<a class="showSingle" target="Fre">Français</a>


<div id="divEng" class="targetDiv">
     <div id="text-top" class="english top">
         <p class="top">ENGLISH TEXT FOR TOP</p>
     </div>
     <div id="text-bot" class="english bot">
         <p class="bot">english text for bot</p>
     </div>
</div>

<div id="divGer" class="targetDiv">
     <div id="text-top" class="deutsch top">
         <p class="top">deutsch text for top</p>
     </div>
     <div id="text-bot" class="deutsch bot">
         <p class="bot">deutsch text for bot</p>
     </div>
</div>


<div id="divFre" class="targetDiv">
     <div id="text-top" class="francais top">
         <p class="top">francais text for top</p>
     </div>
     <div id="text-bot" class="francais bot">
         <p class="bot">francais text for bot</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
          jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
          jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
    });
});
```

jsfiddle here:

- note - i tried getting it to work, and i have a feeling it doesn't because the 'a' tags do not have a 'href'
  [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r80rgqsh/)

Please let me know if theres anywhere to clean the code up whilst also setting 'divEng' to show by default on page load.

Comment: If they're anchors, won't they just redirect ?

Comment: Could just set href="#" to get around redirect.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the code for the links, already have it set to '#'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add more classes to the elements, so they are easier to target.
Then add the language to the anchors without the special characters.

In the click handler, it's then easy to get the language, hide all and then show the selected

```js
$('.lang_selection').on('click', function() {
 $('.lang').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).data('lang')).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text-top-en" class="english lang">
<p class="top">text above buttons</p>
</div>

<div id="text-bot-en" class="english lang">
<p class="bot">text below buttons</p>
</div>

<div id="text-top-de" class="deutsch lang" style="display: none;">
<p class="top">text above buttons in deutsch</p>
</div>

<div id="text-bot-de" class="deutsch lang" style="display: none;">
<p class="bot">text below buttons in deutsch</p>
</div>

<div id="text-top-de" class="francais lang" style="display: none;">
<p class="top">text above buttons in french</p>
</div>

<div id="text-bot-de" class="francais lang" style="display: none;">
<p class="bot">text below buttons in french</p>
</div>

<a href="#" class="lang_selection" data-lang="english">English</a>
<a href="#" class="lang_selection" data-lang="deutsch">Deutsch</a>
<a href="#" class="lang_selection" data-lang="francais">Français</a>
```

Comment: This isn't working either... 
I'm sure its something really simple that I'm missing.... >.<

Comment: If it's not working, you should open the console (F12) and check for errors in your scripts.

Comment: Hi Adeneo, so I've had a look at the console. no errors showing up.

Comment: *i'm calling <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> atm not sure what I'm doing wrong. 
Feel free to IM me. 
Thanks again for your help

Comment: Hi Adeneo,
Is it by any chance, not woring because I have the 'a' links above the div's im trying to hide?

Comment: It works if you add jQuery to your fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/r80rgqsh/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start for you to hide and show languages. You would just have to apply the desired CSS to it.

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  var lang = "." + $(this).attr('data-lang');
  $('.language').hide();
  $(lang).show(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="text-top-en" class="english language">
<p class="top">text above buttons english</p>
</div>
<a href="#" data-lang="english">English</a>
<div id="text-bot-en" class="english language">
<p class="bot">text below buttons english</p>
</div>

<div id="text-top-de" class="deutsch language" style="display: none;">
<p class="top">text above buttons in deutsch</p>
</div>
<a href="#" data-lang="deutsch">Deutsch</a>
<div id="text-bot-de" class="deutsch language" style="display: none;">
<p class="bot">text below buttons in deutsch</p>
</div>

<div id="text-top-de" class="french language" style="display: none;">
<p class="top">text above buttons in Français</p>
</div>
<a href="#" data-lang="french">Français</a>
<div id="text-bot-de" class="french language" style="display: none;">
<p class="bot">text below buttons in Français</p>
</div>

<div id="text-top-de" class="italian language" style="display: none;">
<p class="top">text above buttons in Italian</p>
</div>
<a href="#" data-lang="italian">Italiano</a>
<div id="text-bot-de" class="italian language" style="display: none;">
<p class="bot">text below buttons in Italian</p>
</div>

<div id="text-top-de" class="spanish language" style="display: none;">
<p class="top">text above buttons in spanish</p>
</div>
<a href="#" data-lang="spanish">Español</a>
<div id="text-bot-de" class="spanish language" style="display: none;">
<p class="bot">text below buttons in spanish</p>
</div>


<div id="text-top-de" class="dutch language" style="display: none;">
<p class="top">text above buttons in dutch</p>
</div>
<a href="#" data-lang="dutch">Nederlands</a>
<div id="text-bot-de" class="dutch language" style="display: none;">
<p class="bot">text below buttons in dutch</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for quick reply.
I've made the changes, and for some reason it's not working.
the only things I know about js are things I've learnt along the way.

am I missing something at the top of my js code?
I've got it as a seperate .js file and i'm calling that file in my html <head> tag

Comment: Just had another thought, I've got seperate css for the top/bot div's in each language using their id's - would it be better to use the classes instead?
If so how would I differentiate the classes CSS for the top/bot div's - as these include the length they are away from the top of the parent div.. if that makes sense?

Comment: Are you loading your custom script after jQuery? You can check your console to see if it's giving you any script errors.

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajaz/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="js/lang.js" type="text/javascript">

that's at the top of my html? correct?

Comment: It should be <script src="js/lang.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: ah so <script src="location/lang.js"></script>?

Comment: This still isn't working.. not sure what I'm missing =/

Comment: Can you post the code in your <head>? It seems like you're not loading jquery before it

Comment: All the answers here will work. It seems like you are not loading in your scripts properly. @adeneo answer is the cleanest though.

Comment: I'm an idiot :). i'd written (as i can see in an above comment) /ajaz/ not /ajax/.

Will fix this tomorrow and re-try. and comment whether successfull or not!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it: https://jsfiddle.net/phfva4hk/1/

```
<a href="#" data-language="english" class="the_language_selector">English</a>
<a href="#" data-language="deutsch" class="the_language_selector">Deutsch</a>
<br /><br />
<div id="text-top-en" class="english lang_based">
<p class="top">text above buttons</p>
</div>

<div id="text-bot-en" class="english lang_based">
<p class="bot">text below buttons</p>
</div>

<div id="text-top-de" class="deutsch lang_based" style="display: none;">
<p class="top">text above buttons in deutsch</p>
</div>

<div id="text-bot-de" class="deutsch lang_based" style="display: none;">
<p class="bot">text below buttons in deutsch</p>
</div>
```

and on the JS side:

```
$(".the_language_selector").click(
    function () {
    var the_language_class = $(this).attr("data-language");
    $(".lang_based").hide("slow");
    $("." + the_language_class).show("slow");
  }
);
```

The idea is to use the "data" tags to store which class of divs to show and which to hide. And just so that the previous selection is wiped out, on every language link click, I am also hiding all the divs that have the class "lang_based" (That is to say that divs that are shown or hidden based on language)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="languages">
<div id="text-top-en" class="english">
<p class="top">text above buttons</p>
</div>

<div id="text-bot-en" class="english">
<p class="bot">text below buttons</p>
</div>

<div id="text-top-de" class="deutsch" style="display: none;">
<p class="top">text above buttons in deutsch</p>
</div>

<div id="text-bot-de" class="deutsch" style="display: none;">
<p class="bot">text below buttons in deutsch</p>
</div>
</div>

<a href="#">English</a>
<a href="#">Deutsch</a>
<a href="#">Français</a>
<a href="#">Italiano</a>
<a href="#">Español</a>
<a href="#">Nederlands</a>
```

js script side

```
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $('a').on('click',function() {
        var lang =$(this).text();
        $('#languages').children('div').each(function(){
          if($(this).is('.'+lang) ) {
            $(this).show();
          } else {
            $(this).hide();
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Nope. not working either =/. the URL add's the '#' but thats the only thing changing on the page

Comment: saying line 1 '$' is not defined.

`$(function(){
$('a').on('click',function()
{
var lang =$(this).text();
$('#seat-content').children('div').each(function(){
     if($(this).is('.'+lang) )
    {
        $(this).show();
    }
else
{
    $(this).hide();
}
    })
})
})`

Comment: Is there any error message showing in console @BradCollyer

Comment: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>` Can you put this line in your code

Comment: Added the above call out.
I also didn't include teh drop-down as this is not wanted on the page.
Now when i click either English (default language shown), or Deutsch/French etc, the main image dissappears and the english text stays as active.

Comment: Oh..I am really sorry,that section added by my mistake,first i just check the div hiding with drop down,just forget to remove it@BradCollyer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the click event from jquery:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <a id="en" href="#">English</a>
      <a id="de" href="#">Deutsch</a>
      <a href="#">Français</a>
      <a href="#">Italiano</a>
      <a href="#">Español</a>
      <a href="#">Nederlands</a>
      <div id="text-top-en" class="english">
        <p class="top">text above buttons</p>
      </div>

      <div id="text-bot-en" class="english">
        <p class="bot">text below buttons</p>
      </div>

      <div id="text-top-de" class="deutsch" style="display: none;">
        <p class="top">text above buttons in deutsch</p>
      </div>

      <div id="text-bot-de" class="deutsch" style="display: none;">
        <p class="bot">text below buttons in deutsch</p>
      </div>
      <script src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script>
        //Event handler on deutsch click
        $("#de").click(function(){
          $(".english").hide();    
          $(".deutsch").show();
        });
        $("#en").click(function(){
          $(".english").show();    
          $(".deutsch").hide();
        });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```